# sql developer change a connection password

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to open one of my old connections from SQL Developer, but i forgot its password.
I tried to make it fast with a Show Me Password extension, but there are no saved passwords under the passwords paragraph.
Is it expired and how i can recover it or change it

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Connect as a privileged user (such as `SYS` or `SYSTEM`, if there's no other), and then run

```
alter user your_old_user identified by its_new_password;
```

Then establish a new connection as `your_old_user`.

---

As you didn't use that user for a while, there's a chance that its password has expired and account is now locked. In that case:

```
alter user your_old_user account unlock identified by its_new_password;
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4e816f696235e38f4f238defbef3987e
I don't know why it doesn't find it.
The connection username is petur
There are codes for it in the C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system18.3.0.277.2354\o.jdeveloper.db.connection
https://gyazo.com/02735d0e20b5dfa7a8fe5691006d02a9